# Setting up Firefox with multiple profiles running simultaneously (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, firefox, taskbar, file-shortcut

### The goal

A click on Firefox in the TaskBar starts an instance which asks which profile to use. When that instance runs and the same icon is clicked with middle mouse button (to start a new instance) it shall ask again which profile to use in the new instance. And so on.

If an external program tries to open a link, the first opened instance of firefox shall receive that.

---

### My attempts

**Append `-p` to the shortcut-file**

Will not allow me to open multiple profiles simultaneously.

**Append `-p -no-remote` to the shortcut-file**

Works exactly as I want it with **one exception**: If any external program tries to open a link, it will try to open another instance instead of using the instance I started first.

**Create shortcut 'A' with `-p` and 'B' with `-p -no-remote`; then use 'A' for the first instance and 'B' for the following**

Works completely but I want only **one** icon/shortcut so this is no option.

---

### An idea

Maybe I should use some kind of batch file to detect a running firefox-process and if it finds that start with `-p -no-remote` else with `-p`... but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Hi, do you have still same goal? I've realized how to have two different (separated) icons on task-bar - one for each profile. Could this resolve your issue?